# how to do dynamic routing in codeigniter w/0 db

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

trying to route the page as website.com/'schoolname' . if there is a controller in same name it will go through it .. else it will check whether there is such schoolname in the db if there is one it ll go to its profile page .. if there are no mattches it ll return a 404 page.

code

Routes

```
 $wind =     array("app.php","assignment.php","backup.php","book.php","bulkimport.php","category.php","classes.php","conversation.php","dashboard.php","eattendance.php","event.php","exam.php","examschedule.php","exceptionpage.php","expense.php","feetypes.php","grade.php","hmember.php","holiday.php", "hostel.php","index.html" , "install.php","invoice.php" , "issue.php" ,"language.php", "lmember.php" , "mailandsms.php" ,"mailandsmstemplate.php", "mark.php" , "markpercentage.php", "media.php", "menu.php", "migration.php" ,"notice.php" , "parents.php", "paymenthistory.php" , "paymentsettings.php" , "permission.php", "profile.php", "promotion.php" , "report.php" , "reset.php", "resetpassword.php" , "routine.php" , "sattendance.php", "school.php" ,"schoolyear.php" ,"section.php", "setting.php" , "signin.php" , "signup.php" , "smssettings.php" ,"student.php" , "subject.php" , "syllabus.php" , "systemadmin.php", "tattendance.php", "teacher.php" ,"tmember.php" ,"transport.php" , "update.php" , "user.php" , "usertype.php" , "visitorinfo.php" );



 foreach ($wind as $win)
 {
 $controllers[] =  $win;
  }

   $id = $this->uri->segment(1);


   if (in_array($id.'.php', $controllers)){


   $route[$id] = $id;


  }else{

 $route[$id] = 'school/index/'.$id;

}
```

Controller

```
    public function index($id = null)
{

   $a = $this->systemadmin_m->get_fnall($id);




  if($a != null){

    $this->load->view('front/header');
     $this->load->view('front/includes');
    $this->load->view('front/sindex');
    $this->load->view('front/footer');

}else{


       $this->load->view('errors/notfound');
}


}
```

Comment: sorry guys it was a mistake in the foreach i copied that part   from somewhere.it works perfectly ..

Answer (score 0):

Use a real routing component! Try the symfony or zend framework routers, installable with composer!

Comment: fixed it for now .. will try those